# What PayPal method to use

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Could somebody advice me, which PayPal method use for simple user-to-user payment? Due to logging every payments in my database, im looking for some method, which returns fee amount in IPN message. Exists something like this?

I would use adaptive payment PAY method, but after obtaining a pay key and acomplish the payment using https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay form action, there is no fee information in incoming IPN message. I dont understand, why... Is it purpose?

Is my procedure correct? Or has anybody better solution? Its very important for me, to get a fee amount in IPN.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that with Adaptive Payments there are actually 2 IPN's that could be involved.  When you set the NotificationURL in your API request that is where PayPal will send the App specific IPN.  This will be pretty general info about the fact that a transaction took place, but won't contain much detail about the transaction itself.

The actual receiving account would then trigger its own IPN if it was configured in that account profile, and this would include more details about the transaction including the fee.

You may very well be acting as both, so then you could potentially see 2 IPN's triggered from a single transaction.  One for your app, and one for your PayPal merchant account.

You could also try hitting [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), which returns a FEEAMT, but I'm not 100% sure it works with Adaptive Payments transactions.  I've never tested that specifically.

Comment: I have no access to receiver account. The receivers are my application users. Im sending funds to their paypal accounts. So I have no possibility to configure it in paypal profile. Can it be a problem for me? If it is, do you know about some alternative?

Comment: You could try GetTransactionDetails.  I updated the answer with a link.

Comment: Seems it works with adaptive payment. Finally some way, how to get fee. thanks a lot. But i dont understand, why it is so complex. There are 3 steps to get fee. First, I have to get pay key, then I have to get TransactionId using pay key and  adaptive payment PaymentDetails method... becouse there is no transactionId in first message. And last step is getting transaction detail using GetTransactionDetails... I think, it`s not the only solution and I hope, somebody advice, how to solve it easier way